# Asterisk cannot hear sound on Wifi network only

Tags: asterisk

I've installed Asterisk + FreePBX on CentOS 6.5.

```
Case 1
Asterisk + FreePBX + CentOS 6.5
Phone A - Android 4G newtork (Linphone, PCMA codec)
Phone B - Android Wifi network (Linphone, PCMA codec)
If I can make a call to Phone B from Phone A, it works and answers the phone. 
However, I can only hear sound from Phone A when I speak on Phone B.
```

I thought it is NAT problem, and checked all firewalls for Asterisk. There is no problem with Wifi network either. Is there a way to change NAT settings correctly? Thank you.

Here is the Asterisk CLI logs when I make a call and talk on the phone.

```
  == Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [1004@from-internal:1] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__RINGTIMER=15") in new stack
    -- Executing [1004@from-internal:2] Macro("SIP/1003-0000005e", "exten-vm,novm,1004,0,0,0") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:1] Macro("SIP/1003-0000005e", "user-callerid,") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:1] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "TOUCH_MONITOR=1395938841.94") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:2] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "AMPUSER=1003") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:3] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?report") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:4] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?Set(REALCALLERIDNUM=1003)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:5] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "AMPUSER=1003") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:6] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?limit") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:7] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "AMPUSERCIDNAME=Third") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:8] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?report") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:9] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "AMPUSERCID=1003") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:10] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__DIAL_OPTIONS=Ttr") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:11] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLERID(all)="Third" <1003>") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:12] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?limit") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:13] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Set(GROUP(concurrency_limit)=1003)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:14] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "7?sub-ccss,s,1(macro-exten-vm,1004)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:1] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Return()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:2] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CCSS_SETUP=TRUE") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:3] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?monitor_config,1(macro-exten-vm,1004):monitor_default,1(macro-exten-vm,1004)") in new stack
    -- Executing [monitor_default@sub-ccss:1] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?is_exten") in new stack
    -- Goto (sub-ccss,monitor_default,4)
    -- Executing [monitor_default@sub-ccss:4] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLCOMPLETION(cc_monitor_policy)=generic") in new stack
    -- Executing [monitor_default@sub-ccss:5] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLCOMPLETION(cc_max_monitors)=5") in new stack
    -- Executing [monitor_default@sub-ccss:6] Return("SIP/1003-0000005e", "TRUE") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:4] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "7?agent_config,1():agent_default,1()") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:1] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLCOMPLETION(cc_agent_policy)=generic") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:2] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLCOMPLETION(cc_offer_timer)=30") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:3] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLCOMPLETION(ccbs_available_timer)=") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:4] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLCOMPLETION(ccnr_available_timer)=") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:5] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLCOMPLETION(cc_callback_macro)=ccss-default") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:6] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?Set(CALLCOMPLETION(cc_recall_timer)=)") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:7] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?Set(CALLCOMPLETION(cc_max_agents)=)") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:8] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Set(CALLCOMPLETION(cc_agent_dialstring)=Local/1003_1004@from-ccss-)") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:9] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLCOMPLETION(cc_callback_macro)=ccss-default") in new stack
    -- Executing [agent_config@sub-ccss:10] Return("SIP/1003-0000005e", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:5] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "DB(AMPUSER/1003/ccss/last_number)=1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:6] Return("SIP/1003-0000005e", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:15] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Set(CHANNEL(language)=)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:16] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?continue") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:17] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?Set(__CALLEE_ACCOUNCODE=)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:18] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__TTL=64") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:19] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?continue") in new stack
    -- Goto (macro-user-callerid,s,30)
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:30] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLERID(number)=1003") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:31] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CALLERID(name)=Third") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:32] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CDR(cnum)=1003") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:33] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CDR(cnam)=Third") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:34] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CHANNEL(language)=en") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:2] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "RingGroupMethod=none") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:3] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__EXTTOCALL=1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:4] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__PICKUPMARK=1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:5] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "RT=") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:6] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Macro(vm,novm,DIRECTDIAL,)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:7] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?MacroExit()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:8] Gosub("SIP/1003-0000005e", "sub-record-check,s,1(exten,1004,)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:1] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "REC_POLICY_MODE_SAVE=") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:2] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?check") in new stack
    -- Goto (sub-record-check,s,7)
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:7] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__MON_FMT=wav") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:8] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?next") in new stack
    -- Goto (sub-record-check,s,11)
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:11] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Return()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:12] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Set(__REC_POLICY_MODE=)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:13] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?exten,1") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:14] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__REC_STATUS=INITIALIZED") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:15] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "NOW=1395938841") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:16] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__DAY=28") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:17] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__MONTH=03") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:18] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__YEAR=2014") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:19] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__TIMESTR=20140328-014721") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:20] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__FROMEXTEN=1003") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:21] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__CALLFILENAME=exten-1004-1003-20140328-014721-1395938841.94") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-record-check:22] Goto("SIP/1003-0000005e", "exten,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (sub-record-check,exten,1)
    -- Executing [exten@sub-record-check:1] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?callee") in new stack
    -- Executing [exten@sub-record-check:2] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__REC_POLICY_MODE=dontcare") in new stack
    -- Executing [exten@sub-record-check:3] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?caller") in new stack
    -- Goto (sub-record-check,exten,10)
    -- Executing [exten@sub-record-check:10] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__REC_POLICY_MODE=dontcare") in new stack
    -- Executing [exten@sub-record-check:11] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?record,1(exten,1004,1003)") in new stack
    -- Executing [exten@sub-record-check:12] Return("SIP/1003-0000005e", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:9] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?macrodial") in new stack
    -- Goto (macro-exten-vm,s,15)
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:15] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?clrheader,1()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:16] Macro("SIP/1003-0000005e", "dial-one,,Ttr,1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:1] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "DEXTEN=1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:2] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "DIALSTATUS_CW=") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:3] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?screen,1()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:4] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?cf,1()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:5] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?skip1") in new stack
    -- Goto (macro-dial-one,s,8)
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:8] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?nodial") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:9] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?continue") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:10] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "EXTHASCW=ENABLED") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:11] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?next1:cwinusebusy") in new stack
    -- Goto (macro-dial-one,s,23)
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:23] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?next3:continue") in new stack
    -- Goto (macro-dial-one,s,24)
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:24] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Set(DIALSTATUS_CW=BUSY)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:25] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?nodial") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:26] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?dstring,1():dlocal,1()") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:1] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "DSTRING=") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:2] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "DEVICES=1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:3] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Return()") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:4] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Set(DEVICES=004)") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:5] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "LOOPCNT=1") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:6] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "ITER=1") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:7] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "THISDIAL=SIP/1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:8] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?zap2dahdi,1()") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:1] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Return()") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:2] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "NEWDIAL=") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:3] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "LOOPCNT2=1") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:4] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "ITER2=1") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:5] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "THISPART2=SIP/1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:6] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Set(THISPART2=DAHDI/1004)") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:7] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "NEWDIAL=SIP/1004&") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:8] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "ITER2=2") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:9] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?begin2") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:10] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "THISDIAL=SIP/1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [zap2dahdi@macro-dial-one:11] Return("SIP/1003-0000005e", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:9] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "DSTRING=SIP/1004&") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:10] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "ITER=2") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:11] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?begin") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:12] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "DSTRING=SIP/1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [dstring@macro-dial-one:13] Return("SIP/1003-0000005e", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:27] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?nodial") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:28] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?skiptrace") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:29] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "1?ctset,1():ctclear,1()") in new stack
    -- Executing [ctset@macro-dial-one:1] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "DB(CALLTRACE/1004)=1003") in new stack
    -- Executing [ctset@macro-dial-one:2] Return("SIP/1003-0000005e", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:30] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "D_OPTIONS=Ttr") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:31] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?SIPAddHeader(Alert-Info: )") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:32] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?SIPAddHeader()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:33] ExecIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?Set(CHANNEL(musicclass)=)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:34] GosubIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?qwait,1()") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:35] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__CWIGNORE=") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:36] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "__KEEPCID=TRUE") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:37] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?usegoto,1") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:38] GotoIf("SIP/1003-0000005e", "0?godial") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:39] Gosub("SIP/1003-0000005e", "sub-presencestate-display,s,1(1004)") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@sub-presencestate-display:1] Goto("SIP/1003-0000005e", "state-,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (sub-presencestate-display,state-,1)
    -- Executing [state-@sub-presencestate-display:1] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "PRESENCESTATE_DISPLAY=") in new stack
    -- Executing [state-@sub-presencestate-display:2] Return("SIP/1003-0000005e", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:40] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CONNECTEDLINE(name,i)=fourth") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:41] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "CONNECTEDLINE(num)=1004") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:42] Set("SIP/1003-0000005e", "D_OPTIONS=TtrI") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:43] Dial("SIP/1003-0000005e", "SIP/1004,,TtrI") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/1004
    -- Connected line update to SIP/1003-0000005e prevented.
    -- SIP/1004-0000005f is ringing
    -- SIP/1004-0000005f is ringing
    -- Connected line update to SIP/1003-0000005e prevented.
    -- SIP/1004-0000005f answered SIP/1003-0000005e
```

=============================================================================

SIP contact

Android on Wifi

```
Addr->IP     : 14.63.12.134:5060
Reg. Contact : sip:1000@14.63.12.134
```

Android on 4G LTE

```
Addr->IP     : 223.62.202.25:58184
Reg. Contact : sip:1002@223.62.202.25:58184
```

It looks like Android on Wifi failed to get right address. It doesn't show specific port to send voice.

Comment: what is the output of `asterisk -rvvvvv`and try `sip debug` or `sip set debug on` and configure "nat" and "qualify" (http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+nat)

Comment: I posted Asterisk logs. It looks fine.

Comment: Do you already __forward SIP Ports__ (UDP 5060, 10000-20000) to the asterisk machine on your router/firewall? You need to check the ip's in a rtp debug, you should see something like: `Got  RTP packet from <IP>`, `Sent RTP packet to <IP>`. Activate NAT at your sip.conf's "general" context Setting: `nat=yes`, `externip=<YOUR REAL IP>`, `localnet=<LOCANET/MASK>`.

Comment: @pce Yes. I've opened that ports, changed settings that you mentioned. It is working on LTE network. However, it is not working only on Wifi network at home... very strange..

Answer (score 1):

That's why I love plain-clean Asterisk, your console doesn't get flooded like this for a single call. :)

If you're absolutely sure the codecs are fine, then the audio RTP is not reaching the phone. Check where it's being sent inspecting the SIP INVITE messages (assuming 1003 is the phone not working):

```
> sip show peer 1003
```

Look for the Codecs information. If they're good, look into NAT. Set

```
> sip set debug on
```

Or for a specific peer:

```
> sip set debug on peer 1003
```

Then check your headers, specifically the Contact: header which states 'hey contact me back here'.

If the call is created, meaning the control signaling goes through (you can CALL and HANGUP in either phone) then I'm pretty sure it's a codec issue. If the control is not 100% fine (for example you HANGUP in one phone and the other doesn't know) then it's probably a network issue.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Then check where they're sending/expecting audio using SIP debug.

Comment: Good. I checked contact data where it sends voice. It doesn't have specific port.. now I need to find out how to do it. maybe I need stun server to find it? @CharlieBrown

Comment: To be accurate where to send the voice is decided on each call (INVITE), in the SDP description it includes the port. But I agree that those 2 different contacts are a bit weird. Perhaps you should look into setting SIP ALG in your WiFI router. Sorry I can't help anymore!

Comment: Thanks Charlie! I found that it was NAT problem. I turned on Stun server, and it is working now :)

Comment: Great! These are never easy to catch ;)